# Android APK Installation "Package Installer has Stopped"

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-manifest

I'm developing an app in Android Studio and using the Build APK tool to generate APK files for teammates to test. Recently they started getting an error upon APK installation saying "Package Installer has Stopped" whenever they go to open the .apk file.

The installation has worked up to this point. Recently, an apk that failed to install on a Galaxy S7 Edge and a Note 8 succeeded on an LG V20, if that's worth anything. Also, the significant changes to the app I made in between .apk uploads was writing some java code to open another app on the device after a button click. When the click occurs, either the app will open (if installed) or redirect to the Play Store for the user to install it.

I read around and it seems like some people with this issue received the same message because of some permissions not set in their `AndroidManifest`. Is there a permission needed for opening separate apps? Or is there something else that could cause this issue?

EDIT: Also mentioned that I cannot uninstall already-installed versions of my app. I tried a solution online that clears data and force stops the Package Installer (system app) and uninstalling other apps has become slower.

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cjmb.com.raasrelease01">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".GlobalValue"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_official"
        android:label="@string/icon_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PlanSelectedActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ReportWorkoutActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".DeviceMonitoringActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SubscribedUserActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ChangePasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CreateAccountActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the dependencies in my `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Isn't it related with some Android update? Had problems when running an app after installing Android update.

Comment: Which update would that be? @pb772

Comment: I think you are talking about debug apk for testing right? In that case, how are you generating the debug apk? Are you using the default debug apk which is generated in your `build` folder while you are running your code in your test device during the development time? What is the version of your Android Studio?

Comment: @ReazMurshed I am using (in android studio) Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s). The target directory is /build/outputs/apk/debug. The android studio version is

Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 8, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Comment: Do the testers have the release apk installed in their devices?

Comment: Oh, I see you found the problem. Great to know that. Please mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Appears that I solved my problem.

I uploaded a custom icon for the app. It can be seen in the `AndroidManifest` code:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_official"
```

The dimensions on this icon were too large (>1600x1600). I reduced the same image to < 500x500 using online image reducer (Google around for one). Redid the build for the apk and installed it. I can now install, run, and uninstall the app again.